# Get status of MessagingMenu

Tags: dbus, messaging-menu

Is there a method (using dbus or something else, I would prefer bash/python), to check if the status of the messaging indicator (the one that gets blue if a new message arrives) is currently "Attention" (i.e. there are new messages) or not?

I tried to dig into dbus documentation to see if there is somewhere a property I can read to determine that, but I have been unlucky so far...

I'm running 16.04 if necessary

Comment: Install d-feet (gui d-bus navigator). Then search for `com.canonical.indicator.messages`.  Under `/com/canonical/indicator/messages` > `org.gtk.Actions` it has signal called `changed`. You can monitor it  with `dbus-monitor`. Refer to dbus-monitor wiki for this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks that works, but is not exactly what I need. I don't want to monitor dbus, I want to `dbus-send` something and return an answer that is either true or false